# sass background mixins using url

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

guys i would like to create a background mixin instead writing repeated url

```
 @mixin bgimage($name){
  $url:"../images/$name.png";
 background: url($url);}
```

and,it never accept the valuee to $name variable

i called it by

```
     @include bgimage(name.png);
```

and in css the output is came wrong like this

```
     background: url("../images/$name.png");
```

is there any way to write the url in mixin ? ot how to do it in short way

Comment: fcalderan's solution can even be made marginally more concise by neglecting the declaration of a separate `$url` variable. Holding the targeted URL in its own variable doesn't really confer any added benefit since it is (at least, in this scenario) only used once.
`@mixin bgimage($name) { background: url("../images/#{$name}.png"); }`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try with variable interpolation of `#{$name}`

```
@mixin bgimage($name) {
  $url:"../images/#{$name}.png";
  background: url($url);
}
```

and pass the filename, without extension, as a mixin parameter:

```
@include bgimage(your-png-file-without-extension);
```

since it is already appended in the `$url` variable of your mixin

Comment: yea its works fine coo;.. :)

Comment: Skipping the quote characters in the declaration, but including them when calling the mixin worked for me:
`@include gradient-primary("../img/<filename>.jpg");`.
The
[interpolation syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)
is needed, of course.
Thanks!