# sass default mixin variables path character escaping

Tags: sass

It seems by the conventions of the other mixing I have created and seen that this should work but there is two problems with it that I can not seem to find the solution for .

- The default path if not Quoted throws an error during compilation
- The `url($path)` is not evaluating the $path variable

> ```
> @mixin backgroundCover($path:"./Media/Images/background.png"){
> background-image:url( $path );
> background-repeat:no-repeat;
> background-size:cover;
> }
> ```

What is the proper way to write this function

==================== Worth noting that this issue came up again today

```
 @mixin keyframes( $animationName )
        {
        @-webkit-keyframes #{animationName} {
            @content;
        }
        @-moz-keyframes #{animationName} {
            @content;
        }
        @-o-keyframes #{animationName} {
            @content;
        }
        @keyframes #{animationName} {
            @content;
        }
    }
```

originally #{animationName} was $animationName and winging errors all over the place

Comment: Why is quoting the path a problem?  I cannot reproduce your second point (path *is* evaluated).

Comment: It is not in this instance since url() should have a quoted argument any way. In the circumstance though that I need to have something unquoted I would still like to know how to properly escape the default parameter. The main problem is that $path is not expanding =/

Comment: possible duplicate of [sass background mixins using url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854975/sass-background-mixins-using-url)